Github Action - Invalid login: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failed
I try to send test report of my node.js project with github action automatically.
Here is the relevant part of github action

- name: Send test report email
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
        with:
          server_address: smtp.protonmail.ch
          server_port: 587
          username: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
          subject: Test Report
          body: Test results attached.
          to: <mail_address>
          from: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_USERNAME }}
          attachments: report.png

I always get the error shown below
`Invalid login: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failed`
`EMAIL_USERNAME` refers to my email of proton.me
`EMAIL_PASSWORD`  refers to my email's password of proton.me
I also tried to use username of proton.me account but nothing changed. I still got the same error.
Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

https://proton.me/support/smtp-submission: "Note: Your Proton Mail login or mailbox passwords will not work with SMTP, and you should never use them with third-party clients." You need to create an SMTP token.
